# Offline Language Translator using c# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, translate

I am trying to create an offline version of a language translator (to convert **English to Portuguese** and Vise-versa) in Windows application using c#.

Is it possible to create translator application **without internet** and without using any third party api's? And It having any pre-defined resource file for a complete translation?

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Unfortunately though, this question is way too broad for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this offline but you have a lot of issues to complement that:

- You will need something to parse the words(in this case english/portuguese) and detect what language is originaly.
- You will need some database, to store all the words you wanna translate for the application get them. That's why using API google translate or something like this it's easier.
- If you really want to make it offline you will need a lot of work, because you really need to store the words somewhere...
- You will something to convert the verbs (i'm portuguese, and we have a lot of verbs and conjugal times) and you need some script or something to convert that, or your application will not recognize.

Comment: Thanks for your valid points Mikev.And one more clarification, can we have any offline pre-defined database/resource file? or will create from scratch?. I need to translate any English word to Portuguese instead of any static(list of text) to convert.

Comment: @Tafros Yes it's possible to have an offline database/resource file.